# using generate-id() for xsl:result-document filename and linking to HTML

Tags: html, xml, xslt, xslt-1.0, saxon

I'm using xslt to transform a big xml into smaller interlinking html files. I've got troubles with the generate-id() function, as the generated id's are not the same for html href="" and the id's in the filenames

I create the following files via xsl:result-document:

> index.html | d1e83523.html | d1e83524.html | d1e83525.html | ...

index.html should contain a list with links to the other *.html files

---

**index.html** that I want, but all I get are different id's:

```
      <ul>
         <li><a href="d1e83523.html">Sample 1</a></li>
         <li><a href="d1e83524.html">Sample 2</a></li>
         <li><a href="d1e83525.html">Sample 3</a></li>
      </ul>
```

---

**xsl** to create **index.html**:

```
<xsl:template match="lab/*">
    <xsl:result-document encoding="utf-8" method="html" href="HTML_out/index.html" >
                <html>
                    <head></head>
                    <body>
                        <ul>
                            <xsl:for-each select="chapter/heading">
                                <li>
                                    <a href="{generate-id()}.html">
                                        <xsl:value-of select="foo"/>
                                    </a>
                                </li>
                            </xsl:for-each>
                        </ul>
                    </body>
                </html>
            </xsl:result-document>
 </xsl:template>
```

---

**xsl** to create the other ***.html**:

```
<xsl:template match="chapter/*[not(self::heading)]">
        <xsl:for-each select=".">
            <xsl:result-document encoding="utf-8" method="html" href="HTML_out/{concat(generate-id(), '.html')}" >
                <html>
                    <head></head>
                    <body>
                        <xsl:apply-templates/>
                    </body>
                </html>
            </xsl:result-document>
        </xsl:for-each>
    </xsl:template>
```

---

**xml-sample** (note: multiple *description*-like-structured elements following)

```
<lab>
    <description>
        <chapter>
            <heading>Example</heading
            <operation>other elements</operation>
            <operation>other elements</operation>
            ...
        </chapter>
        ...
    </description>
</lab>
```

I'm grateful for every help!

EDIT: I'm using generate-id() to get an unique filename for those many files

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you change `<xsl:for-each select="chapter/heading">` to `<xsl:for-each select="chapter/*[not(self::heading)]">` then your index generation processes the same elements for which you generate result documents and the generated ids should match. However, you need to run both XSLT snippets inside the same transformation to ensure getting the same ids, if you have separate stylesheets then generate-id is not guaranteed to give the same result.

Comment: Thank you so much! Unfortunately I still don't quite understand how the generate-id() funktion works... I've tried differend to get to the same node-sets inside of the functions brackets, but nothing worked for me. However this solution did the trick!